# Continues Trigger GeoFence Event

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location, android-geofence

GeoFence triggering issue

I have setup geofence in my app, 
I am using IntetnService for the handle trigger event.

My issue is with trigger event many time.

Suppose i am at 1 Location inside Geofence, unfortunately some time enter or exit event trigger,
Then i do like check the geoEvent.getTriggerdLocation() properties and check with geo fence radius,

if the trigger location to geo fence location distance greater then geofecen radius  then an then i will release my exit event functionality,

but eventually geofence trigger event 2 3 km far even i already entered in fence and my above logic will fail. see snap

[image]

i want some solid fix for these.

Location is on with High priority

this will happening more when i will near to border of fence

Add geo fence list, as of now i am using only one fence.

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId(String.valueOf(loGeoFenceModels.liGeoFenceID))
                    .setCircularRegion(loGeoFenceModels.ldGeoLatitude, loGeoFenceModels.ldGeoLongitude,
                            loGeoFenceModels.lfRadius)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
```

PendidngIntentService

```
moGeofencePendingIntent = getGeofencePendingIntent();
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi
                .addGeofences(moLocationClient, getGeofencingRequest(), moGeofencePendingIntent)
                .setResultCallback(this);
```

getGeofencingRequest() AND  moGeofencePendingIntent

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder().setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofences(mGeofenceList).build();
}



private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (moGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return moGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(moContext, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent
    // back when calling addgeoFences()
    return PendingIntent.getService(moContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;
import android.R.bool;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.usage.UsageEvents.Event;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.location.Location;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
    super(TAG); // use TAG to name the IntentService worker thread
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

private static String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofencingEvent event) {
    String transitionString = GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(event.getGeofenceTransition());
    List<String> triggeringIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
        triggeringIDs.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    return String.format("%s: %s", transitionString, TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringIDs));
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    Log.i(TAG, "Geofencing Event : " + event);
    if (event.hasError()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error : " + event.getErrorCode());
        return;
    }

    // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
    if (event.getGeofenceTransition() == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Enter");
    }
    if (event.getGeofenceTransition() == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Exit");
    ?
    String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
    Log.i(TAG, "GeofencingEvent description : " + description);
}
```

}

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

i stuck in this issue since many days, please help to finish the issue.

Comment: post more code.

Comment: @kishorejethava is it ok?

Comment: Have you checked `Geofence` request Id? It might be possbile that both are different request Id.

Comment: No there is a only one geo fence as of now, so no chance for the unique request id.also i have print log. @kishorejethava

Comment: How long radius of region?

Comment: min 500 meter to 2 kilometer   @kishorejethava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one patch to avoid unwanted or dummy events.

you can get location on trigger time

```
Location loTriggerGeoFenceLocation = moEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
long ldAccuracy = loTriggerGeoFenceLocation.getAccuracy();
```

now store your geo fence location lat long and radius.
not get trigger lat long and check the distance between trigger location and geo fence location lat long.  if the distance are less then radius it should be the enter and is distance is more then radius it should be exit event

```
 if (event.getGeofenceTransition() == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

    ldGeoLatLong = moSharedPreferenceManager.getGeoFenceTimeLocation();
    Location loExistGeoFenceLocation = new Location("");
    loExistGeoFenceLocation.setLatitude(ldGeoLatLong[0]);
    loExistGeoFenceLocation.setLongitude(ldGeoLatLong[1]);

    String lsRadius = moSharedPreferenceManager.getGeoFenceRadius();
    float lfRadius = Float.parseFloat(lsRadius);
        Log.i(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Exit");
        float lfDistance = loTriggerGeoFenceLocation.distanceTo(loExistGeoFenceLocation);
        if (lfDistance >= lfRadius && ldAccuracy <= 100f) {
            moSharedPreferenceManager.setGeoFenceExit(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the points you should keep in mind when use `Geofence` in `Application`

From official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#BestPractices)

- **Choose the optimal radius for your geofence**

> For best results, the minimium radius of the geofence should be set
>   between 100 - 150 meters. When Wi-Fi is available location accuracy is
>   usually between 20 - 50 meters. When indoor location is available, the
>   accuracy range can be as small as 5 meters. Unless you know indoor
>   location is available inside the geofence, assume that Wi-Fi location
>   accuracy is about 50 meters.
>
> When Wi-Fi location is not available (for example, when you are
>   driving in rural areas) the location accuracy degrades. The accuracy
>   range can be as large as several hundred meters to several kilometers.
>   In cases like this, you should create geofences using a larger radius.

- **Use the dwell transition type to reduce alert spam**

> If you receive a large number of alerts when driving briefly past a
>   geofence, the best way to reduce the alerts is to use a transition
>   type of GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL instead of
>   GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER. This way, the dwelling alert is sent only
>   when the user stops inside a geofence for a given period of time. You
>   can choose the duration by setting a loitering delay.

Comment: 1. Choose the optimal radius for your geofence
 - it will more then 700 meter.

2.Use the dwell transition type to reduce alert spam - 
I know that but i want this functionality for city area. sometime happen when user didn't stop inside fence just go through the fence.

Comment: did you tried with radius between 100m to 300m? because in my case, I had set 200m so it was triggering around 5m after `Exit` or `Enter`

Comment: Buddy, in my case i am already in fence, and it will trigger exit event,even i am so far(almost 200 meter) from the fence border.